# Why is a function with default-assigned argument(s) not accepted as 0-arg Generator?

Tags: c++, stl, generator, default-arguments

The following code attempts to use `ns::generateInt()` as the `Generator` argument to `std::generate_n()`:

```
// main.cpp

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

static int _tmp = ( srand( time( NULL ) ), 0 );

namespace ns
{

  int generateInt( int offset = 0 )
  {
    return offset + rand() % 128;
  }

}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  int tmp = ns::generateInt(); // Fine to call ns::generateInt() w/ 0 args

  std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v ),
                   5,
                   ns::generateInt ); // Not accepted as 0-arg Generator
  return 0;
}
```

This code generates the following compile error:

```
$ g++ --version && g++ ./main.cpp
g++ (GCC) 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:62,
                 from ./main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_OIter std::generate_n(_OIter, _Size, _Generator) [with _OIter = std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int> >; _Size = int; _Generator = int (*)(int)]’:
./main.cpp:26:36:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:4493:18: error: too few arguments to function
 4493 |  *__first = __gen();
      |             ~~~~~^~
```

I know that the `std::generate_n()` signature takes a `Generator` function/functor that takes 0 arguments, but the argument to `ns::generateInt()` has a default value; and as shown above, in non-templated code, I can invoke `ns::generateInt()` with no arguments.

If the only change made to the above code is this...

```
  int generateInt( /*int offset = 0*/ )
  {
    return /*offset +*/ rand() % 128;
  }
```

...then it compiles just fine:

```
$ g++ ./main.cpp
$
```

**What's going on from the compiler's perspective here?** My default-argumented generator function is *invokable* with 0 arguments, so **why is it not usable as the `Generator` argument to `std::generate_n()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `generateInt()` has a default argument value does not change the fact that it has an argument, which you can see in the error message:

`_Generator = int (*)(int)`

**The default argument value is not part of the function's type.**

When you call `generateInt()` *directly*, the compiler knows the full declaration of `generateInt()` and so it knows that it can allow you to omit the defaulted argument value.

But, inside of `std::generate_n()`, the compiler does not know that the `_Generator __gen` input argument is pointing at your `generateInt()` function.  All it knows is that `__gen` is pointing at *some function* whose type takes an `int` argument, **any knowledge of a default value is lost**.  And since `std::generate_n()` is not supplying that argument value in the call to `__gen()`, you get the compiler error.

The `Generator` template parameter of `std::generate_n()` *requires* a [Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) type that takes no arguments.  So, the *only* way you can use your 1-argument `generateInt()` as-is with `std::generate_n()` is to wrap it inside a 0-argument lambda or functor, eg:

```cpp
std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v ),
                   5,
                   []{ return ns::generateInt(/*0*/); } );
```

```cpp
struct genInt
{
    int operator()(){ return ns::generateInt(/*0*/); }
};

std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v ),
                   5,
                   genInt() );
```

Answer (score 2):

From the reference for [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n):

> g -   generator function object that will be called.
>   The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> Ret fun();

Note that it says the *signature* must be `Ret fun();`, *not* that the argument is *invokable* with 0 arguments.

You could wrap the call in a lambda quite easily so as not to change the code in `ns`:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v),
                5,
                [] { return ns::generateInt(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments do not alter the signature of a function. The signature still contains the argument types that have default values. When a function takes an argument that is a pointer to another function requiring no arguments, but the argument is given a pointer to a function that does take arguments (with or without default values), then you have a type mismatch.

Comment: Great thought pointing out function pointers as an example of why this rule applies!